# Is the function $(e^z - 1) / z$ defined at $0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

For the function $f(z) = \frac{e^z-1}{z}$, it seems that there should be a singularity at $z=0$, but if the numerator is expanded, we get $f(z) = \frac{-1 + 1+z+z^2/2! + ...}{z} = 1+ \frac{z}{2!}+...$ which seems to make it well-defined at every point, including $z=0$.

How do you reconcile with the fact that when you substitute $z=0$ into the original equation, you obviously get an undefined singularity, whereas after some algebraic manipulation its behaviour at $z=0$ seems to be different? Is this function an entire function?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, $f$ is not defined at zero, because the algebraic definition does not make sense there. What *is* true, however, is that $f$ coincides at all points except zero with an entire function; namely, the one whose power series starts with $1 + z^2 / 2!$ that you've written.

We can extend the definition of $f$ and simply declare its value at zero to be $1$, in which case the extended function is entire.

Comment: but if $e^z$ is equivalent to the power series $1+ z + \frac{z^2}{2!} + ...$, then why is $f$ and the extended function not equivalent?

Comment: The function and its extension have different domains, and are therefore not the same function.

Answer (score 0):

If you just substitute $0$ into the function, which is a wrong approach, you'll see the function gives you nothing. It basically gives you a $0/0$ form, indeterminate.

In the limit meaning, you can use De l'Hopital rule:

$$\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(z)} = \lim_{z\to 0}\frac{f'(z)}{g'(z)}$$

In this case you get

$$\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{e^z-1}{z} = \frac{0}{0}$$

which allows you to use Hopital rule, getting

$$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{e^z-1}{z} = \lim_{z\to 0}\frac{e^z}{1} = e^0 = 1$$

So your function is defined in zero, and it's limit is $1$.

Comment: I always find it strange when people use L'Hospital when the limit is *literally* the definition of the derivative of $e^z$ at zero....

Comment: That was meant to be a different explanation.